# Como obtener de una lista de objetos A los objetos que faltan o que no estan en una lista B en C#

Tags: c#

Hola  tengo una lista de objetos del siguiente modelo:

```
 public partial class ArticuloSC
    {
        [JsonProperty("CLASIFICACION 1")]
        public object Clasificacion1 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("COSTO PROMEDIO")]
        public object CostoPromedio { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("DESCRIPCION")]
        public string[] Descripcion { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ARTICULO")]
        public string Articulo { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("CLASIFICACION 2")]
        public object Clasificacion2 { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("PRECIO")]
        public object Precio { get; set; }
    }
```

Y otra lista de objetos del siguiente modelo:

```
public class ArticuloFC
{
    public object categoryId { get; set; }
    public object cost { get; set; }
    public DateTime? dateCreated { get; set; }
    public object dateDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime? dateUpdated { get; set; }
    public bool deleted { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public object extId { get; set; }
    public object familyId { get; set; }
    public int? id { get; set; }
    public object maxDiscount { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
    public bool notAvailable { get; set; }
    public int? permissionLevel { get; set; }
    public object price { get; set; }
    public bool readOnly { get; set; }
    public int? salesRepIdCreated { get; set; }
    public object salesRepIdDeleted { get; set; }
    public int? salesRepIdUpdated { get; set; }
    public object stock { get; set; }
}
```

Lo único que tienen en común estas clases es el campo o la propiedad extId y Articulo. Entonces lo que quiero es que teniendo la lista de ArticuloSC, poder saber cuales artículos por medio del campo Articulo hacen falta o no estan en la lista de ArticuloFC.
Hasta el momento lo estoy intentando de esta forma:

```
//Obtengo los que ya existen en las 2 listas
                var existentes =(from A in articulos
                                 join FC in articuloFCs
                                on A.Articulo equals FC.extId
                                select A.Articulo).ToList();
                //Luego obtengo los que no estan descartando los que ya estan 
                var inexistentes =(from A in articulos
                              where  !existentes.Contains(A.Articulo)
                              select A.Articulo).ToList();
```

Sin embargo cuando reviso la lista de inexistentes obtengo códigos que ya estan en la lista de los existentes. Como puedo obtener en los inexistentes solamente los que de verdad no estan en la lista de existentes los cuales se unen por un join?

Para explicarme mejor. Yo voy a tener en la lista de ArticuloSC artículos que ya existen en la lista de ArticuloFC pero también voy a tener artículos en la lista de ArticuloSC, artículos que todavía no existen en la  lista de ArticuloFC y esos son precisamente los que necesito identificar.

Comment: Investiga sobre el operador de conjunto Except en linq

Comment: porque usas object al definir la propiedad  public object categoryId y no usas int u otro tipo de dato? veo que tienes muchas propiedades con tipo object https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_data_types.htm#:~:text=The%20Object%20Type%20is%20the,predefined%20or%20user%2Ddefined%20types.

Comment: Que hay de malo con usar object?? El tipo int, double etc hereda de object, entnces que hay de malo?? Porque algunos son objetos literalmente , es decir que en el json vienen como algo asi [ "a","b"]  y para no tener que estar definiendo una clase para todo sino tengo que definir como mil clases. Mejor deserealizo como dictinary<>  o como arreglo o lo que sea en lugar de tener que estar creando clases